# No access to the double click function in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, click

Good day, please tell me, I have a program and there you need to create an object with 1 click, and using a double wedge to delete it. So I have in c# wpf double click does not work.The code below:

XAML:

```
  private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is ICalcefication)
            {
                UIElement activeCalcification = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
                _maker.DeleteMarker(canvas, activeCalcification);
            }
        }
        else if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 1)
        {
            Point location = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(canvas);
            _maker.AddMarker(canvas, location, _calcificationType);

        }
    }
```

*.Cs:

```
  private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is ICalcefication)
            {
                UIElement activeCalcification = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
                _maker.DeleteMarker(canvas, activeCalcification);
            }
        }
        else if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 1)
        {
            Point location = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(canvas);
            _maker.AddMarker(canvas, location, _calcificationType);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You shared the cs instead of the XAML

Comment: yes: XAML:              <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                    AllowDrop="True"
                    MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">

Answer (score 0):

Each double click starts with one click. You should wait.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;

private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        cts.Cancel(); // It is double click; wait is over, cancel single click
        if (e.OriginalSource is ICalcefication)
        {
            UIElement activeCalcification = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
            _maker.DeleteMarker(canvas, activeCalcification);
        }
    }
    else if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Point location = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(canvas);
                _maker.AddMarker(canvas, location, _calcificationType);
            });

        });
    }
}
```